# PHP and MySQL Ranking

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I have this table in MySQL:

```
id | name  | points
1  | John  | 9
2  | Bart  | 7
3  | Billy | 14
```

I would like to have a table in HTML / PHP where he prints this:

```
Name   Points
Billy  14
John   9
Bart   7
```

How can I do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service, you have to atleast try something and show this to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a query like :

```
SELECT name, points FROM your_table ORDER BY points DESC
```